# How to develop on a Python package?

Tags: python, module

I want to contribue to a Python module that is hosted with git. So I clone the module with `git clone https://github.com/a_python_module && cd a_python_module`.

Then I can edit the sources, and to test my changes I run `python setup.py install` which can take a while depending on the module. The other way would be to directly edit the sources in `/usr/lib/python 2.7/site-packages/...` then copy the changes back in the Git repository.

Is there a better workflow than these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is the 3rd word from your question title:

```
python setup.py develop
```

It sets the package in development mode, i.e. links the current source folder to the site-packages; or you can do this [directly with `pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs):

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/a_python_module#egg=SomeModule
```